# Nuances of where to define a variable in ruby code

Tags: ruby

I've just started learning ruby, and the position of where variables are defined somewhat elude me. For example, why does this code work:

```
def two_sum(nums)
  result = nil 
  i = 0   
  while i < nums.length 
    k = (nums.length - 1)
    if nums[i] + nums[k] == 0 
      result = [i,k]
    end 
    i += 1 
    k -= 1 
  end 
  return result 
end
```

And why does this code not work:

```
def two_sum(nums)
  result = nil 
  i = 0 
  k = (nums.length - 1)
  while i < nums.length 
    if nums[i] + nums[k] == 0 
      result = [i,k]
    end 
    i += 1 
    k -= 1 
  end 
  return result 
end
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This question would be easier to answer if you defined what "work" vs "does not work" means to you. What result did you expect? What did you see instead (an error, a crash, an unexpected value)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you code might just have a bug

```
while i < nums.length 
  k = (nums.length - 1)
  ...
  k -= 1 # this statement has no effect!
end
```

Above, the value if `k` is always `(nums.length - 1)` because you reassign it at the begin of each iteration. The other statement has no effect.

```
k = (nums.length - 1)
while i < nums.length 
  ...
  k -= 1 
end
```

Above, the value of `k` starts at `(nums.length - 1)` in the first iteration and is then reduced by `1` for each iteration.

Pro tipp —

It is very unusual in Ruby to use a `for/while/until` loop. If you want to loop over all elements use `each` or `each_with_index` instead

```
array.each { |each| ... }
array.each_with_index { |each, n| ... }
```